# how to horizontally align 3 subviews of a UIView with NSLayoutConstraint visual format

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following setup:

1. A UIView with size (40,40)
2. 3 subviews of this view, each with frames (0,0,40,40)

Now I'd like for this setup to have the following constraint hold at all times:

**H:|-10-[v1]-10-[v2]-10-[v3]-10-|**

Which implies the following desired behavior throughout the lifecycle of the superview:

1. Immediately after setting the constraints, the views should autolayout as shown above.
2. Since the superview itself is only (40,40), it should automatically resize to make the layout possible.
3. From there onwards, changing the width of any of the subviews should layout the views again so that they still stick to the layout format.

My approach so far is like so:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    if (self) {
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.v1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        self.v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        self.v3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

        [self addSubview:self.v1];
        [self addSubview:self.v2];
        [self addSubview:self.v3];
        NSDictionary *views = @{@"v1" : self.v1, @"v2" : self.v2, @"v3" : self.v3};
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[v1]-10-[v2]-10-[v3]-10-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"10":@10} views:views]];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

but I get the conflicting constraints message:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xed9f040 H:|-(10)-[UIView:0xed9ad30]   (Names: '|':MyView:0xed9a040 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xed9f270 H:[UIView:0xed9ad30]-(10)-[UIView:0xed9c370]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xeda3770 h=&&& v=-&- UIView:0xed9c370.midX == 0.5*MyView:0xed9a040.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xeda37a0 h=&&& v=-&- UIView:0xed9c370.width == MyView:0xed9a040.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xed9f270 H:[UIView:0xed9ad30]-(10)-[UIView:0xed9c370]>
```

My guess is that it has to do with the superview not being able to resize. But I'm overall somewhat confused about it. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You want to make sure that for your programmatically created views that you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`, e.g.:

```
self.v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

If you want these three subviews to be the same width as each other, spaced 10 apart, you might use a horizontal VFL of:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[v1]-10-[v2(==v1)]-10-[v3(==v1)]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Clearly, with spacing of 10 points between each of the subviews, the superview would have to be wider than 40 points wide. For example, if the superview is 100 points wide, once you factor out the 10 point spaces between the subviews (leaving 60 points of width for the subviews, themselves), the constraints system would make the subviews 20 points wide each.

And, if you want those to be 40 points tall, you might define vertical constraints (as well as define how far from the top of their superview you want them, too):

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v1(40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v2(40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v3(40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

This defines them to have zero offset from their superview, but a height of 40 points.

And, if you've defined the views based upon constraints, you don't need to use `initWithFrame`, but rather just use `init`. When using auto layout, you don't generally specify `frame` for anything, but rather let the constraints dictate the size.

Comment: I tried your approach and it got me somewhat on the right track. However, looks like I need to define at least an initial width in the constraint for each view? So is there no way to encode "whatever width the views need to be to be x spaced apart"? Also, it seems that even if I encode specific widths and the subviews lay out the right way, the frame of the superview that contains them stays at (0,0,0,0). The only reason the subviews are visible is cause clipsToBounds gets set to NO. Is there a way for the superview to really resize?

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz Let's move this to chat, as it is likely to be an extended conversation: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37690/how-to-horizontally-align-3-subviews-of-a-uiview-with-nslayoutconstraint-visual-f